# asciidoc: source block aligned into nested list item

Tags: asciidoc

I'm trying to arrange tabulation.

I need a source block is nested block inside a nested list item:

list:

```
. Restore buckups
 * List logical names:
+ 
 RESTORE FILELISTONLY from DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/xxxx.bak'
+
Sample output:
[source,options="nowrap"]
----
include::doc/samples/logical_names.out[]
----
 * Another nested list element...
```

Currently, it appears as:

[image]

I need source block is arranged at the same level of nested list item.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 5):

In your example source, the `source` block terminates the `Sample output:` paragraph. Since there is no continuation included, it also terminates the list item, and the list, because a source block is not a list item (by itself).

The solution is to include a [continuation](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/lists/continuation/) between the two elements:

```
Sample output:
+
[source,options="nowrap"]
```

Note that you'll need to add a blank line between the source block and the next list item, to provide a clear separation between the two.
After above change:
[image]